# No Mapping Found for HTTP Request in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting a no mapping found for the dispatcher servelt. can you please point me where the issue is in the code. I'm very new to Spring MVC

My Error is (My pom has the artifactId of EnhancedRoyaltyTool)

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher
```

My web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  




<!--    <listener> -->
<!--         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> -->
<!--     </listener>    -->
</web-app>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acxiom.saas.royalty.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Controller file

```
@Controller
public class SearchController 
{   

    @ModelAttribute("search")
    public Search getSearch()
    {
        return new Search();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/")
    public String homePage()
    {
        System.out.println("home");     

        return "search";        
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/payRoyalties", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchJobs(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("search") Search search)
    {
        System.out.println(search.getOesNumber() +"TEST");
        model.addAttribute("test", "testing modelmap");

        return "payRoyalties";      
    }

}
```

my search.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search For Jobs</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form   method="POST" modelAttribute="search" action="payRoyalties"    >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="oesNumber">OES Number</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="oesNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

I do have a payRoyalties.jsp file and Search model.

Comment: Could you search "Mapped URL onto " to check which controller is mapped to your particular url?

Comment: Can you explain me in more detail ?I'm very new to spring mvc. The intial home page itself is not loading when i deploy the application.

Comment: Swith your log level to DEBUG, and check your log. Is there any line like "Mapped "{[/payRoyalties],......}" onto public java.lang.String SearchController .searchJobs(org.springframework.ui.Model) ..." when you startup the server?

Comment: You simply aren't mapping any method to `/EnhancedRaoyaltTool`. So it's no wonder you got the error `No Mapping Found for HTTP Request [/EnhancedRaoyaltTool/]`. P.s. This is extracted from a comment to an answer that should have been a comment as well.

Comment: Provide us the URL you are accessing and exception log!

Comment: Going through all the comments.. it is clear there a host of problems here. 1. You need the ContextLoaderListener uncommented, 2. You put a snippet for exception trace below, it clearly shows there is no mapping found for URI "EnhancedRoyaltyTool" which is not mentioned anywhere in your question. Please update your question to show relevant information.

Comment: My Pom has the artifactId of EnhancedRoyaltyTool

Answer (score 1):

There is no mapping named search in your class.

You need to add  @RequestMapping(value ="/search") before your getSearch() Method

Comment: One thing hare, handlers has nothing to do with the name of jsp, you can rename your jsp to anything and alter the return value in your getSearch method. You have added `@ModelAttribute("search")` on one of your methods, this is used in your handler where you have added the same annotation on one of the method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your web servlet configuration. I have seen this case before, when Spring confuses between mapping URL with mapping to JSP files.

In short, instead of:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You should try:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then try access your controller with `/payRoyalties.html`

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I change to this my application fails to deploy.

Comment: LOG : SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EnhancedRoyaltyTool]]

Comment: @SandeepRao: it should not fail. There must be problems in other places, could you provide me the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute("search")
public Search getSearch()
{
    return new Search();
}
```

Above part of your code is confusing, you have "search" in @ModelAttribute while there is no "search" for @RequestMapping, what are you trying to do with this.

please provide log for any more assistance.

Comment: Aug 02, 2013 8:51:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: @ModelAttribute search is directly used in the search.jsp page. My understanding is that when your search.jsp loads it automatically binds call the getSearch method and binds it to the search object in jsp page.

Comment: yes, i missed that you have search as model defined in one of your handler methods, this seems fine. The problem seems very obvious it says `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/] in DispatcherServlet`, it means you need to have a handler method mapped to this url something like `@RequestMapping("/EnhancedRoyaltyTool")`. Hope this is the only thing wrong

Comment: My Pom has the EnhancedRoyaltyTool as the artifact ID

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController {
    …
}
```

Comment: I dont think, that is the problem. as he is not hitting url /search", see for tag "action="payRoyalties" and there is already a mapping defined for this. log will clear things little more.